# Swing mousePressed for more things

Tags: java, swing

Basicly this is a part of my code:

```
package Piano;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel
{
int r = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));

    for (int i = 60; i < 1800; i += 150)
    {
        drawKeys(g, i, 450, 150, 550);
    }       
}
public void drawKeys(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    r++;

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    if (e.getX() > x && e.getX() < x + width && e.getY() > y && e.getY() < y + height)
                    {
                        System.out.println(r);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

and I was wondering if it is possible to add all the mousePressed locations in a single loop. Well, in my case it doesn't work, because for all keys it prints the same, which is the last known 'r' (System.out.println(r)). How would you approch this?

Comment: You mean like a list of coordinates?

Comment: Well I am making a piano so I wanna detect which of those keys is currently pressed down, so every key needs a mousePressed.

Comment: Does my answer aid you?

Comment: I though about that method too, but wanted to do with JPanel, so I used camiskr version and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Never add a MouseListener (or any listener) to a component in a painting method. Every time Swing repaints the component you will add another listener.

> I was wondering if it is possible to add all the mousePressed locations in a single loop.

You would never add a MouseListener for each pixel location. That is not how a MouseListener works.

Instead you:

1. create an ArrayList of Rectangles to represent each piano key
2. you add a single MouseListener to your component
3. When a MouseEvent is generated you use the Point from the MouseEvent and iterate through the ArrayList of rectangles using the `Rectangle.contains(...)` method to see if the Rectangle contains the mouse point. If so, then you do your custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

Going off what you said in your comment you could do something a little like this. Create a `JButton` for each key, or preferably a `JButton Array` for all the keys. Add an action listener to them all. Then when a `JButton` is clicked play the corresponding sound.

A simple example

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GUITemplate {
    private JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("This is my title");
    private JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton a = new JButton("a"), b = new JButton("b"), c = new JButton("c"), d = new JButton("d"), e = new JButton("e");
    private CustomMouseListener cML = new CustomMouseListener();

    private void runGUI() {     
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myMainWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        createFirstPanel();
        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);
        myMainWindow.pack();
        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createFirstPanel() {
        firstPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        firstPanel.add(a);
        firstPanel.add(b);
        firstPanel.add(c);
        firstPanel.add(d);
        firstPanel.add(e);

        int panelComponents = firstPanel.getComponentCount();

        for(int i = 0;i<panelComponents;i++) {
            if(firstPanel.getComponent(i) instanceof JButton) {
                JButton temp = (JButton) firstPanel.getComponent(i);
                temp.addMouseListener(cML);
                firstPanel.getComponent(i).setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private class CustomMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mE) {
            if(mE.getSource() == a) {
                System.out.println("a");
            }

            if(mE.getSource() == b) {
                System.out.println("b");
            }

            if(mE.getSource() == c) {
                System.out.println("c");
            }

            if(mE.getSource() == d) {
                System.out.println("d");
            }

            if(mE.getSource() == e) {
                System.out.println("e");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GUITemplate().runGUI();
    }
}
```

In this example, a letter is printed to the terminal instead of a sound being played and it looks nothing like a piano but the JButtons could be made to look like piano keys and it would be easy enough to get it to play correct sounds.

**Edit**

I changed code to use a `MouseListener` just incase you desperately wanted to use one.  It works the same except you a `MouseListener` to each `JButton` instead of an `ActionListener`.